# Webpack shows warning twice

Tags: webpack, eslint, create-react-app, typescript-eslint

I have an ejected CRA and I recently upgraded Webpack to version 5, and now after using `npm run start` I get warning twice (attached), is there any option to show it only once?
I noticed that on new CRA project this happens too when using ESLint webpack plugin.

```
Compiled with warnings.

src/app/apollo/apollo.ts
  Line 15:7:   Unexpected console statement  no-console
  Line 18:21:  Unexpected console statement  no-console

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in src/app/apollo/apollo.ts
  Line 15:7:   Unexpected console statement  no-console
  Line 18:21:  Unexpected console statement  no-console

webpack compiled with 1 warning
No issues found.
```

Comment: were you ever able to fix this? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

I did not encounter a method to show the warning only once, but only to disable.
To disable the warnings you can refer the [following post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/eslint-unexpected-console-statement):

> The ESLint error "eslint (no-console) Unexpected console statement" is shown when you use methods on the console object, e.g. console.log().
>
> To resolve the issue, set the no-console rule to off in your .eslintrc.js file to disable the rule.

> - Create a `.eslintrc.js` file if you don't already have one.
> - The file should be located in the root directory of your project, right next to your `package.json` file.
> - Add the following rule to the `rules` object in your `.eslintrc.js` file to disable the `no-console` rule.

```html
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'no-console': 'off',
    },
};
```

Comment: Please read the question properly. He asks how to only show the warning once and not how to disable the error...